# Android ViewSwitcher Not Working

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

In my android app, I need to switch the views when Timer is elapsed.

```
_timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => {
    ViewSwitcher v =  FindViewById<ViewSwitcher>(Resource.Id.switchr);
    v.ShowNext();
};
```

But it works on click,

```
 FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.del).Click += (sender, e) => {
    ViewSwitcher v =  FindViewById<ViewSwitcher>(Resource.Id.switchr);
    v.ShowNext();
};
```

How can i make it work?

Please help,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working:

```
RunOnUiThread (() => { 
     ViewSwitcher v =  FindViewById<ViewSwitcher>(Resource.Id.switchr);
     v.ShowNext();
});
```